# How to delete tables and database using Sqiltehelper in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a class call DatabaseHandler extending SQLiteOpenHelper. I want to explicting deleted the database or table on the button click. What are the parameters I have to pass to the call method? Here is the code for reference:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

 // All Static variables
// Database Version
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EmployeeDB";

// Contacts table name
public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

}

 /**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(id, cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
public void DeleteDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db,String table)
{


    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + table);
   db.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hard to answer without more context, but the ultimate sqlite query would be:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename");
```

Where db is a reference to a SqliteDatabase object.

and to delete database

```
 context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 8):

The code below deletes your tables from DB:

```
db.execSQL("delete from " + DBNAME);
```

To delete database:

```
myCtx.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

where myCtx is the current context, it should not be null.

To delete a row:

```
db.delete("'" + DBNAME+ "'", "Key" + "=" + rowID, null);
```

Comment: Accidentally you answer in same manner. :).I like your answer +1 to you

Comment: how to delete a single value inside the row? as for example:
`database: banco
table: contato
row: nome` how do i delete a value inside the row named: "nome" ?

Comment: myCtx.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME); works but db.execSQL("delete from " + DBNAME); causes error no such table

Comment: db.execSQL("delete from " + DBNAME); will delete ONLY DATA in tables not tables themselves.

Answer (score 6):

`SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase` can get the `SQLiteDatabase` class, `SQLiteDatabase.delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` can delete table.

if you want to delete database, you can directed delete the database file, the path:

`/data/data/package_name/databases/db_name`

Comment: SQLiteDatabase.delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) will only delete DATA in the table, NOT TABLE itself. Table will be left intact.